# Java script then chaining loses context of this

Tags: javascript, promise

I am jumbled up with the .then chaining in Java script. Trying to figure out couldn't solve the below problem.

What I am trying to achieve is: 
I have two arrays this.arrayA and this.arrayB and functionA and funcitonB populates them respectively and then I want to use those two array in funcitonC.

```
return functionA(this)  //returns promise resolve , populates this.arrayA
.then(functionB(this))  //returns promise resolve , populates this.arrayB
.then(functionC(this))  //returns promise rejected if condition=true else resolves promise
```

I am trying to pass "this" context by assigning it as below but I always looses the reference and in functionB I always get output of functionA.I have tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
var self = this;
 return functionA(this)  //returns promise resolve , populates this.arrayA
.then(functionB.bind(self))  //returns promise resolve , populates this.arrayB
.then(functionC.bind(self))  //returns promise rejected if condition=true else resolves promise 

var _ = require('loadash');
functionA(that){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve(
     _.each(that.items1, function(item1){
          var someStruct = {
              name: item1.name,
              type: item1.type
          }
          that.arrayA.push(someStruct);
        }       
     )       
   });
}

functionB(that){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve(
     _.each(that.items2, function(item2){
          var someStruct = {
              name: item2.name,
              type: item2.type
          }
          that.arrayB.push(someStruct);
        }       
     )       
   });
}

functionC(that){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){         
     _.each(that.arrayA, function(someItems){
         _.find(that.arrayB , function(someMoreItems){
               if (someItem.name === someMoreItems.name && someItem.type != someMoreItems.type){
                 reject(Error("it's broken"))
               }else{
                 resolve()
               }
         });             
     });
   });
 }
```

Can you please educate me so I can solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: without seeing what each function does, who can say what the problem is ... the first snippet was doomed to fail because all functions were called immediately ... the second snippet looks like it could work (you don't even need the self var by the way, just bind each function to `this` instead - which is different to what you are doing in the first snippet) - but without seeing what the functions do, who knows

Comment: show the code of `functionC`

Comment: and B and A to see what is really happening

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated the code now for all funcitons

Comment: you can't have a function argument called `this` ... can you?

Comment: oh yes certainly js will throw syntax error.I will edit the snippet but you understood the intent what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store context `this` to a variable and use that variable every time.

Comment: the variable also looses the context after functionA.

Comment: I was losing the context `this` every time but yes you were right that assigning it to a variable in every function did the job.I was assign it once only at the beginning of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a function instead of an object to the `Promise` constructor.

So, instead of

```
new Promise({})
```

You need

```
new Promise(function(){})
```

---

**Update - Guess 2:**

You are binding the outer `this` to `this` of the functions, which is however never used. You want to bind the first parameter, not `this`.

Try changing

```
functionX.bind(self)
```

Into

```
functionX.bind(null, this)
```

Comment: This is just a guess as you haven't provided us with a complete example. Also, you should tag all the libraries (like underscore) your example uses.

Comment: Yeah syntax wise you are right.I did used new Promise(function(){}) but missed it in snippet above.But that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Check the answer for another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with the above code is how Promise is resolved and rejected in functionC. Because once you set a state for Promise it will not change in case of functionC couple of iterations have set the promise to resolve and the condition that was satisfying the if statement wasn't able to set is to reject() again. So I have set a Boolean flag and evaluated the flag outside the both loops. And also I need to `return` the state of Promise just setting it doesn't return it.

```
 return functionA(this)  //returns promise resolve , populates this.arrayA
.then(functionB.bind(this))  //returns promise resolve , populates this.arrayB
.then(functionC.bind(this))  //returns promise rejected if condition=true  else resolves promise 


functionA(that){
    self.arrayB = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    _.each(that.items1, function(item1){
      var someStruct = {
          name: item1.name,
          type: item1.type
      }
      resolve(that.arrayA.push(someStruct));
    }       

  });
 }

functionB(){
 var self = this;
 self.arrayB = [];
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {     
 _.each(self.items2, function(item2){
      var someStruct = {
          name: item2.name,
          type: item2.type
      }
      resolve(self.arrayB.push(someStruct));
    }            
 });
}

functionC(){
  var self = this;
  var promiseStatus = false;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){         
 _.each(self.arrayA, function(someItems){
     _.find(self.arrayB , function(someMoreItems){
           if (someItem.name === someMoreItems.name && someItem.type != someMoreItems.type){
              promiseStatus = true;              
           }
       });           
 });
 if (promiseStatus){return reject(Error('it broken'))}
 else {return resolve();}
 });
 }
```